# Missing argument for parameter #2 in call to Alamofire.request(URLRequestConvertible)

Tags: alamofire

Trying to pass an Authentication header in, using the recommended approach of a custom URLRequestConvertible.

So here is my URLRequestConvertible object that conforms to the protocol:

```
class SecureJSONRouter : URLRequestConvertible {

var type: String
var token: String
var parameters: [String: AnyObject]


init(typevar: String, tokenvar: String, parametersvar: [String: AnyObject]) {
    type = typevar
    token = tokenvar
    parameters = parametersvar
}

var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
    let URL = NSURL(string: da_url)!
    let URLRequesting = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(type))
    let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON
    URLRequesting.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    return encoding.encode(URLRequesting, parameters: parameters).0

}
}
```

It's basically a place to store a few things, like a bit of URL, and a token, and a way to create a NSURLRequest with a full URL, the JSON parameters, and the header field for authorization.

When I try to call it like this:

```
    let myUrlRequest: URLRequestConvertible = SecureJSONRouter(typevar: "locations", tokenvar: token!, parametersvar: parameters)

    Alamofire.request(myUrlRequest).response{ (req, resp, data, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            println(req)
            println(resp)
        } else {
            println("saved \(data)")
        }
    }
```

it won't compile, gives me a "Missing argument for parameter #2 in call" error, at the request line.

Any ideas?

PS: I did have my SecureJSONRouter thingy as the recommended Enum instead of a Class, but I got the same error.  I was looking at the protocol definition, and figured there's no reason it can't be a simpler (class) in my case, so I changed it.  Still the same error.

Comment: I'm using the enumeration and see the same problem. However, it only pops up when I shoot the response to a delegate method via the closure.

Comment: I assigned the Alamofire.request to a variable. Then did variable.response{<insert closure here>}. This seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the clue Travis.  Sadly, it didn't help.  It seems like maybe a Swift compiler issue though.

Comment: The Alamofire.request method is simply `public func request(URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible) -> Request {
    return Manager.sharedInstance.request(URLRequest.URLRequest)
}`  So I tried changing the call to Manager.sharedInstance.request directly and now I get compiler errors `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__TMaC9AlamoFire7Manager", referenced from:`

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a few possible culprits here. First off, are you sure you're calling `Alamofire` and not `AlamoFire`? I've seen people make that mistake before.

As for the sample code you posted, it didn't compile for a few different reasons. I couldn't reproduce exactly the same compiler errors you were seeing, but here's a slightly modified version of you original post that does compile.

```
class SecureJSONRouter : URLRequestConvertible {

    var type: String
    var token: String
    var parameters: [String: AnyObject]


    init(typevar: String, tokenvar: String, parametersvar: [String: AnyObject]) {
        type = typevar
        token = tokenvar
        parameters = parametersvar
    }

    var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
        let URL = NSURL(string: "http://httpbin.org")!
        let URLRequesting = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(type))
        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON
        URLRequesting.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        return encoding.encode(URLRequesting, parameters: parameters).0

    }
}
```

Then here's an example of calling your `SecureJSONRouter`.

```
let token: String? = "my_fancy_token"
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = ["sample_parameter": "sample_parameter_value"]
let myUrlRequest: URLRequestConvertible = SecureJSONRouter(typevar: "locations", tokenvar: token!, parametersvar: parameters)

Alamofire.request(myUrlRequest).response{ (req, resp, data, error) in
    if (error != nil) {
        println(req)
        println(resp)
    } else {
        println("saved \(data)")
    }
}
```

That is compiling with Xcode 6.1.1 against the Alamofire 1.1.3 release. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a whirl and let you know.

Comment: Didn't work :(.  It strikes me that perhaps I'm not using the Alamofire 1.1.3 release.  How would I know?

Comment: It completely depends on how you added Alamofire to your project. If you cloned the repository, just pull on master and you'll have the latest version. If you downloaded the zip archive from Github, then I'd suggest you download the latest version from [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/archive/master.zip) and add your code back in. If you are using CocoaPods, then update the version to 1.1.3 and run `pod update`.

Comment: The fastest way to ensure you have things set up right would be to just re-download the latest version of Alamofire from [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/archive/master.zip). Then add the two code blocks paste in the answer above into the Alamofire playground and everything should work properly.

I just tried this and everything works properly.

Comment: Hi @music_and_cities, did you end up figuring this out? If my answer helped you along the way, could you mark it as such to be a good community user? Cheers.

Comment: Hi @cnoon It didn't work and I couldn't figure out why.  I abandoned Alamofire :(.  I tried to upvote your answer but apparently I don't have enough reputation.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah that's too bad. You can still mark it as the answer though if you like. Either way, sorry Alamofire didn't work out. We're working to get it fully completed as fast as possible.